# IE 10.0.9200.1686, going into compatibility mode when "503" is in the copy of the site! Is this an IE bug?

Tags: internet-explorer

My site forces IE to render in the highest mode like most sites do with

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

Today.. we are getting reports from all IE users the site is not working. I went and tested it myself.. the site is going into compatibility mode.

After a bunch of narrowing things down.. i found that the text "503" in the copy is the problem. I removed "503" and all is fine. I change it to "5O3" and it's fine. What the heck is going on? Is this is a bug in IE?

Comment: no one is going to believe me.. but in the footer of my site there is a phone number.. 503.xxx.xxx if i take away the 503 all is fine.. WTF???